# OneNote like web clipping software for notes, code examples, and articles on Mac OS?

Tags: code-snippets

As a developer I find I am gathering more and more information from blogs and other resources from the web. Whether it be tips on configuring Drupal on IIS7 or tips on using the Entity Framework I find I am looking for a way to capture and organize content from the web. I also would like to be able to edit and annotate content to be able to add my own notes and remove add banners or any other content not related to what I am capturing.

When I used Windows OneNote seemed to fit the bill but I have recently moved to Mac OS and I am looking for an equivalent software package. I could run OneNote in a VM but would prefer to have a Mac OS native app. Here are some of the things I am looking for ..

1. Native app rather than web based. Because a web based product could go out of business and my collection could be lost.
2. Ability to organize and handle a large amount of data.
3. Good web clipping ability. So much of my content comes from the web.

   Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I would answer my own question with information on what I found. There ws no shortage of good apps on the Mac for note taking, web clips, and information storage.

### Native Mac OS apps

---

**DEVONthink (http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonthink/)**

This is the application I decided to go with. It is expensive ($150 for Pro Office) but I really liked how it used the file system as it's storage medium and not a single database file. The fact that it has an nice iPhone and iPad app (DEVONthink 2 Go) make it my number one choice. Tagging and folder hierarchy was something I liked and really nice search capabilities. Also, built in OCR.

**YoJimbo - http://www.barebones.com/products/yojimbo/**

Very nice application with nice interface and nice reviews. I just didn't like how all content was saved to a single database file. Nice iPad app also.

**Eagle Filer - http://c-command.com/eaglefiler/**

Very similar to DEVONthink (minus the OCR) but the price was very affordable and it used the file system to store files in native format. I would have chose Eagle Filer if it had a companion iOS app.

**Together - http://reinventedsoftware.com/together/**

I thought Together had a really nice interface. I thought it was very similar to Yojimbo but no companion app (which YoJimbo has)

**Curio - http://www.zengobi.com/products/curio/**

This was an awesome (but expensive) application. In the end I found it to be more suited to creating content rather than storing it. I might look into this as a solution to brainstorming and content creation and use something like DEVONthink to store the content. Very generous trial period.

**VooDooPad - http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/**

VooDooPad got a lot of nice reviews. However, I wasn't too fond of the interface.

**Circus Ponies Notebook - http://www.circusponies.com/**

I personally didn't like the interface of Circus Ponies Notebook however this is a subjective thing. I did not like how a clipping service had to be created in order to import content.

### Web Based Tools

---

Though I prefer a solution that ran as a native Mac OS app, I came across some nice web based applications.

**ZoHo Notebook - http://notebook.zoho.com**

**Mnemonic - http://www.memonic.com/home**

**SpringPad - http://springpadit.com/home**

**Evernote - http://www.evernote.com**

**UberNote - http://www.ubernote.com/webnote/pages/default.aspx**

**MediaWiki - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki**